# If $X$ is a real random variable then for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists a $K$ such that $P (|X|> K) \lt \epsilon$

Tags: probability-theory

I need to determine if this statement is true or false, could you help me?

> If $X$ is a real random variable then for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists a $K$ such that $P (|X|> K) \lt \epsilon$

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you done so far?

Comment: I think that you might want to assume finite expected value of $X$ to show what you're trying to show.

Answer (score 2):

The events $\{|X| > 1\} \supseteq \{|X| > 2\} \subseteq \{|X| > 3 \} \supseteq \cdots$ are a nested sequence of sets whose intersection is the empty set. You may have seen a result that then implies that $\lim_{K \to \infty} P(\{|X| > K\}) = P(\varnothing) = 0$. (If you haven't seen this, you can derive it from the [axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Third_axiom) of probability.)